# Get an attribute of a dom node

Tags: java, xml, jaxp

I am trying to get an attribute of an xml node example:

```
<Car name="Test">
</Car>
```

I want to grab the name attribute of the car node.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();          
Document doc = db.parse(configFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();           
NodeList layerConfigList = doc.getElementsByTagName("CAR");
Node node = layerConfigList.item(0);
// get the name attribute out of the node.
```

this is where i get stuck because the only  method that looks like i can use is getAttributes() with returns a NamedNodeMap and im not sure how to extract it from that.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Your node is an Element so you just have to

```
Element e = (Element)node;
String name = e.getAttribute("name");
```

Comment: How can we get value by names.If i want only car1 ? eg  <Car name="car1">
</Car><Car name="CAR2">
</Car><Car name="CAR3">
</Car>

Answer (score 19):

you can do it without using elements, like this:

```
//HtmlTag represents any arbitrary node that you are trying to get its "car" attribute 

if("HtmlTag".equals(node.getNodeName()))
 String nodeContent=node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("car").getNodeValue()
```