# XML file reading attributes value in java

Tags: java, xml

I have this data in the xml file:

```
<manufacturer>Audi</manufacturer>
    <model>Q3</model>
    <production-year>2011</production-year>
    <horsepower>150</horsepower>
    <consumption type="fuel">7.6</consumption>
    <price>36430</price>
```

And I wrote the following code that lets me read all the nodes from the file.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = null;
            try {

                builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

                Document document = builder.parse(new File(fileName));

                Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();

                NodeList nodes = rootElement.getChildNodes();
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nodes.item(i);

                    if (node instanceof Element) {
                        Element car = (Element) node;

                        String id = car.getAttribute("id");
                        String manufacturer = car.getElementsByTagName("manufacturer").item(0).getTextContent();
                        String model = car.getElementsByTagName("model").item(0).getTextContent();
                        String production_year = car.getElementsByTagName("production-year").item(0).getTextContent();
                        String hp = car.getElementsByTagName("horsepower").item(0).getTextContent();
                        **String type = "";**
                        String fuelConsm = car.getElementsByTagName("consumption").item(0).getTextContent();
                        String price = car.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent();
```

My question is how do I read the value of the attribute type="" in the xml file and get it as a String?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5895228/14419

Comment: It returns an empty String when I do it like that.

Comment: fwif, this is a lot of code to parse a bit of xml. I would suggest you have a look at simplexml. Its premise is that you create a class with the right annotations to allow it parse your xml directly into a coherent java object tree. You just give it the annotated object schema, it then does all the parsing. It handles attributes too.

Answer (score 2):

I used this to get the needed result.

```
Node typeNode = car.getElementsByTagName("consumption").item(0);
String type = "Type : " + ((Element) typeNode).getAttribute("type");
```